# Laplace Transform Injectivity

Tags: laplace-transform

Intuitively how can the Laplace transform be injective? You are taking an integral with limits $0$ and $\infty$. So you don't care about the function before $0$.
Define $g(x)=x^2$ for $x>0$ and $g(x)=0$ for $x \leq 0$ 
Define $f(x)=x^2$ for $x>0$ and $f(x)=-x$  for $x \leq 0$

$f$ and $g$ must have the same Laplace transform by definition right? 
Yet they are not equal. Can someone please explain?

Comment: You are certainly correct - uniqueness refers to a class of functions with domain the range of integration defining the Laplace transform. For a quick argument that seems right, see http://www.ctr.maths.lu.se/media/MATC12/2013ht2013/uniqueness.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-st} dt$ should be thought as the Laplace transform of a function defined only on $t \in [0;\infty[$ or as the bilateral Laplace transform of a function $f(t)$ being $0$ for $t<0$
- the Laplace transform $$\int_a^\infty f(t) e^{-st} dt$$ is injective (in the almost everywhere sense) on functions defined on $[a;\infty[$ for which it converges when $Re(s)\to \infty$

  (often $a=0$ but depending on the function it can be another value, and it  can even be $-\infty$ but in that case it becomes the bilateral Laplace transform)
- the bilateral Laplace transform is injective on functions defined on $\mathbb{R}$ for which it converges when $Re(s) = c$ (for a fixed $c$) and there  it coincides with the Fourier transform of $f(t) e^{-ct}$ .
- note that $-\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{-st} dt = 1/s$ for $Re(s) < 0$ and $\int_{0}^\infty e^{-st} dt = 1/s$ for $Re(s) > 0$ :

  $\implies$ many functions have different **inverse** Laplace transforms, depending on the assumed domain of convergence.

so it is not injective anymore without the convergence assumption, this is why the domain of convergence is so important.

Comment: How can a be less than 0?

Comment: Is it like you say- these functions must be 0 from a up to 0 if that's the case?